# Обрезать border

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Как обрезать border? Совсем не нашёл информации.

На изображении пример, обрезать может понадобиться и больше.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.round {
  background: black;
  border: 6px solid brown;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="round"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8gu4sy9q/1/

Comment: `clip-path: polygon(...)`

Comment: Хм.. В вопросе обрезка рваная, а во всех ответах просто убирается кусок границы...

Comment: @Qwertiy, полагаю, что автор воспользовался инструментом "ластик" в какой-то проге вроде редактора скриншотов, причем радиус инструмента оставил минимальным)) А пытался он зачистить только границу и ровно четверть ее с 9:00 до 12:00))

Comment: @Leonid, но я когда открыл вопрос, ожидал такие же ответы увидеть, а там ничего нет :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Прямо так, как на скриншоте, т.е. рваный край? Тогда SVG и маскирование в помощь. Если просто часть окружности (сегмент), то тогда так:

```css
.round {
  background: black;
  border: 6px solid brown;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  border-top: 6px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="round"></div>
```

Если ориентироваться только на современные браузеры, то код можно немного сократить, используя градиенты и, при этом, угол может быть произвольным:

```css
.round {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, black 94px, transparent 95px),
    conic-gradient(brown 0 115deg, transparent 115deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="round"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Скажите, пожалуйста, а как обрезать больше? Я поигрался со значениями и что-то не так просто это

Comment: @ModaL: если четвертями вырезать, то применить аналогично к `border-left` и др. Если произвольный размер, то посложнее будет - это уже гуглить _радиальный прогресс-бар_.

Answer (score 3):

### SVG решение

Используется две окружности:

Первая окружность это чёрный фон и при радиусе равном `100px` у второй окружности при ширине обводки `stroke-width="10"` радиус выбираем равным `95px`, чтобы края окружностей совпали. Известно, что строка симметрично располагается относительно своей центральной оси. 5px внутрь, 5px снаружи.

Поэтому внешний край внутренней окружности сольется с первой, чёрной окружностью. `(95+5=100px)`

Обводка внутренней окружности будет показана не полностью, так как у sstroke-`dasharray="447.45,149.15"` длина черты равна 447.45, а пробел равен `149,5`.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" >
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="black" /> 
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="95" fill="none" stroke="#A5282B" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="149.15" stroke-dasharray="447.45,149.15" />
</svg>
```

Длину обводки можно увеличивать, уменьшать, при желании попиксельно, изменяя параметры stroke-ddasharray:

***Анимация стирание линии***

при анимации пробел достигает максимума = 596.6

```
values="
  447.45,149.15;
  0,     596.6"
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" >
    
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="black" /> 
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="95" fill="none" stroke="#A5282B" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="149.15" stroke-dasharray="447.45,149.15" >
         <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="2s" values="447.45,149.15;0,596.6" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
      </circle>
</svg>
```

***Анимация рисования линии***

values="
0,596.6;
447.45,149.15"

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" >
    
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="black" /> 
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="95" fill="none" stroke="#A5282B" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="149.15" stroke-dasharray="447.45,149.15" >
         <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="2s" values="0,596.6;447.45,149.15" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
      </circle>
</svg>
```

***Изменение положения линии***

Против часовой стрелки

Изменяются параметры stroke-dashoffset, то есть изменяется начальное положение отступа

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" >
    
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="black" /> 
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="95" fill="none" stroke="#A5282B" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="447.45,149.15" >
         <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="2s" values="0;596" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
      </circle>
</svg>
```

*По часовой стрелке*

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" >
    
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="black" /> 
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="95" fill="none" stroke="#A5282B" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="447.45,149.15" >
         <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="2s" values="596;0" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
      </circle>
</svg>
```

### Решение CSS

Переносим атрибуты окружностей в правила CSS

```css
.circle2 {
fill:none;
stroke:#A5282B;
stroke-width:10;
stroke-dashoffset:149.15;
stroke-dasharray:447.45,149.15;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" >
    
    <circle class="circle1" cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="black" /> 
      <circle class="circle2" cx="100" cy="100" r="95" />
</svg>
```

Анимация рисования сектора

```css
.circle2 {
fill:none;
stroke:"#A5282B;
stroke-width:10;
stroke-dashoffset:149.15;
stroke-dasharray:447.45,149.15;
animation: dash 2s ease infinite;
}
@keyframes dash {
0%{stroke-dasharray:0,596.6; }
100%{stroke-dasharray: 447.45,149.15;}
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" >
    
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="black" /> 
      <circle class="circle2" cx="100" cy="100" r="95" fill="none" stroke="#A5282B" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="149.15" stroke-dasharray="447.45,149.15" >
         <!-- <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" dur="2s" values="0,596.6;447.45,149.15" repeatCount="indefinite" />  -->
      </circle>
</svg>
```